# Path wildcards not working with system.js

Tags: javascript, jasmine, angular, systemjs

According to the system.js [documentation](https://github.com/google/systemjs/blob/master/README.md#paths-configuration), it should be possible to configure **paths** for system.js with **wildcards**.  However, I have been unable to get this to work.  I have a specRunner with jasmine unit tests, and I followed the [angular2 testing tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/first-app-tests.html) to insert a script section so that specs show up.  However, this requires me to manually import *each and every spec*, when I would like to import ***.spec.js** to bring in all the tests.  Here is my SpecRunner.html showing which code works and which does not.

```
<script>
    // Configure systemjs to use the .js extension for imports from the src/js folder
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'src/js': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });

    // Import spec files: Does NOT work
    System.paths['specs'] = 'src/js/*.spec';
    Promise.all([
        System.import('specs')
    ])

    // Import spec files: Does work
    System.paths['specs'] = 'src/js/greeter.spec';
    Promise.all([
        System.import('specs'),
    ])

    // Import spec files: Does work
    Promise.all([
        System.import('src/js/greeter.spec')
    ])
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to configure a path for system.js using **wildcards**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths should contain wildcard in both key and value. SystemJS needs to know, what you're mapping.

```
...
// Should work like this
System.paths['specs/*'] = 'src/js/*.spec';
Promise.all([
    System.import('specs/greeter')
])

//Here, you're essentially aliasing
System.paths['specs'] = 'src/js/greeter.spec';
Promise.all([
    System.import('specs');
    // above is equivalent to:
    System.import('src/js/greeter.spec'),
])
```